# How to pull from a remote branch `someBranch` to a local branch `sonOfSomeBranch`?

Tags: git, branch, git-workflow

So, my teammate and I have these branches: `master`, `someBranch` and `sonOfSomeBranch`. The last one, as you might have guessed, was branched off `someBranch`. I have all of them both locally and remotely, tracked.

I have pushed code to my `sonOfSomeBranch`, but my teammate also did some work on the `someBranch` in the meantime. Now I want to pull what she has done into my `sonOfSomeBranch`.

Can this be done, and if yes, how? I only thought of pulling her code from `someBranch` and adding it manually to `sonOfSomeBranch`, but there has to be a smarter solution.

Answer (score 1):

Pull `someBranch` and merge it into `sonOfSomeBranch`:

```
git checkout sonOfSomeBranch
git fetch origin someBranch:someBranch
git merge someBranch
git push origin sonOfSomeBranch
```

Or pull `someBranch` and rebase `sonOfSomeBranch` on top of it:

```
git fetch origin someBranch:someBranch
git rebase someBranch sonOfSomeBranch
git push --force origin sonOfSomeBranch
```

Comment: But the thing is that I still want to have 2 separate branches, just with the `sonOfSomeBranch` having her + my code. It's more important for the `someBranch` to stay intact because everything there works for now. I just want it as a basis for developing another feature in `sonOfSomeBranch`.

Comment: @Cydonia Merge doesn't remove branches, both branches can be used to add more commits.

Comment: Okay, thank you for taking the time to help me!